# Push-уведомления пользователей при обновлении/добавлении/удалении записей в БД Firestore

Tags: android, firebase, firestore, android-push-notification

Разрабатываю приложение на Android (расписание рейсов) и возникла потребность уведомлять все устройства об изменениях в БД расписания: добавление рейса, изменение времени отправления, отмена рейса, задержки и т.д.
Изначально использовал Service с Listener, но он живет не долго, соответственно не надежен, решил настроить Firestore так, что при любых изменениях в БД отправлялись уведомления по рейсам на все устройства, где установлено приложение. Единственное что удалось найти это оф. документацию по Function и триггерам, но как эти условия прописывать и куда не совсем понятно (что то про Node.js и серверы, но я не использую свой сервер). На русском языке документации еще меньше.
Прошу подсказать как добавить в Firebase данный функционал автоматической рассылки уведомлений, где можно почитать с реальными примерами?

Comment: Так понимаю, что надо развернуть функцию на сервере Firebase через CLI на языке JS, который надо еще выучить ... Если я прав буду благодарен за ссылку на небольшой туториал по данной теме.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да, вы совершенно верно подметили, что надо писать на NodeJs. 
Вот вам небольшой пример:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();
// функция, отсылающая уведомления, если произошло изменение документа entryId
exports.notifyClient = functions.firestore
.document('Collection/{entryId}')
.onUpdate((change, context) => {
  const newValue = change.after.data();
  var status = "";
  if(newValue.status == "Что-то со статусом"){
        status = "Статус " + newValue['someValue'];
  }else{
        status = newValue['someValue'];
  }
  var userRef = admin.firestore().collection('Users').doc(newValue.clientID);
  return userRef.get().then(doc =>{
        if(doc.exists && doc.data().token){
              const token = doc.data().token; // token девайса пользователя
              const payload = {
                    data: { 
                           sound: "default",
                           badge: "1",
                           title: "Уведомление",
                           tag: "entry",
                           body: status
                    }
              };
              admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token, payload);
        }
  })
```

});